# Deploy ejb-jar to be used by multiple wars (Glassfish)

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish-3, ejb-3.1

We have a project that creates a jar file containing JPA entity and service classes to access a database.  We have a number of different applications that need to make use of this jar file. We would like to deploy the JPA jar file as an ejb-jar and have the other apps make use of it via a client jar file included in the war.

Along with Entity classes, our JPA project has a generic service interface defined as follows:

```
public interface GenericService {

    <T> T create(T t) throws Exception;

    <T> T find(Class<T> t, Object id) throws Exception;

    <T> T update(T t);

    List<?> findWithNamedQuery(String queryName) throws Exception;

    List<?> findWithNamedQuery(String queryName, int resultLimit) throws Exception;

    List<?> findWithNamedQuery(String namedQueryName, Map<String, Object> parameters) throws Exception;

    List<?> findWithNamedQuery(String namedQueryName, Map<String, Object> parameters, int resultLimit) throws Exception;

    <T> List<T> findWithNativeQueryListResult(String sql, Class<T> type) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    <T> List<T> findWithNativeQueryListResult(String sql) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    <T> T findWithNativeQuerySingleResult(String sql, Class<T> type) throws IllegalArgumentException;

    <T> T findWithNativeQuerySingleResult(String sql) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}
```

which is implemented in a stateless session bean:

```
@Stateless
@EJB(name = "java:global/DataService", beanName = "DataService", beanInterface = DataService.class)
@Local
public class DataService implements GenericService {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName = "database")
    private EntityManager em;

    protected EntityManager getEntityManager() {

        return this.em;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T create(T t) throws IllegalArgumentException, EntityExistsException, PersistenceException {

        em.persist(t);
        return t;
    }

    .... etc ....
}
```

We use Maven for our builds and set it up to generate a client jar:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-ejb-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <!-- this is false by default -->
      <generateClient>true</generateClient>
      <ejbVersion>3.1</ejbVersion>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

and have set up an empty ejb-jar.xml file:

```
<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" version="3.1" metadata-complete="false">
    <enterprise-beans>
    </enterprise-beans>
</ejb-jar>
```

The client file generated is used as a dependency in our war projects:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>my.package</groupId>
    <artifactId>data-model</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <classifier>client</classifier>
</dependency>
```

When we deploy both ejb-jar and war files, all looks okay.  When we try to access the service/entity classes from the war application, we get:

```
[#|2014-06-02T11:14:34.323-0600|WARNING|glassfish3.1.2|javax.enterprise.system.container.ejb.com.sun.ejb.containers|_ThreadID=276;_ThreadName=Thread-6;|javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.mapLocal3xException(BaseContainer.java:2314)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2096)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1994)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:222)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:89)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy133.createBatch(Unknown Source)
        at my.package.app1.__EJB31_Generated__BatchProcessor__Intf____Bean__.createBatch(Unknown Source)
        at my.package.app1.BatchRestService.createBatch(BatchRestService.java:58)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

... snip ...

Caused by: javax.ejb.TransactionRolledbackLocalException: Exception thrown from bean: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: my.package.datamodel.entity.Batch.__jr_selector__(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.checkExceptionClientTx(BaseContainer.java:5074)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4906)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.StatefulSessionContainer.postInvokeTx(StatefulSessionContainer.java:1648)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2045)
        ... 78 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: my.package.datamodel.entity.Batch.__jr_selector__(I[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;
        at my.package.app1.BatchProcessor.createBatch(BatchProcessor.java:394)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.runMethod(EJBSecurityManager.java:1052)
        at org.glassfish.ejb.security.application.EJBSecurityManager.invoke(EJBSecurityManager.java:1124)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.invokeTargetBeanMethod(BaseContainer.java:4180)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.__intercept(BaseContainer.java:5368)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.intercept(BaseContainer.java:5348)
        at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:214)
        ... 76 more
```

Obviously, there's no method defined on our Batch entity class `__jr_selector__`, so where is this coming from?  How do I debug this?

Any advice on how we're setting up the ejb-jar and/or war to use it would be appreciated as well.

We are deploying to a Glassfish 3.1.2.2 server.

Comment: Are you using JRebel?

Comment: Did you try if it works without JRebel?